# EF Core Migration of SSIS dtsx file

Tags: entity-framework, ssis, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.2

Is it possible to include an SSIS package file (.dtsx) as part of an EF Core 2.2 Migration, such that the migration installs the package on the target server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Migration, you can include arbitrary SQL scripts with [MigrationBuilder.Sql()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations#using-migrationbuildersql).  And there's a set of [stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-deploy-project-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15) you can use to deploy an SSIS project or individual packages to the SSIS catalog.

This is one way to handle SQL Server artifacts that aren't directly supported by EF migrations.  However, the need to deploy things other than your database schema is a indication that you should *strongly consider* using [SQL Server Data Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/ssdt/) (which has first-class support for SSIS) to manage your [SQL Server DevOps](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/sql-devops/), instead of EF Migrations.